# Using C in R package bool parameter is always true

Tags: r, c

I have a function in C that gets run from R via `.Call` and the boolean parameter always gets evaluated as `true`. Here's a minimal reproducible example:

```
library(inline)
dummy <- cfunction(signature(x = "bool"), 
body = '

  int val = x?0:1;
  
  SEXP fake = allocVector(LGLSXP, 5);
  SEXP ans = allocVector(LGLSXP, val);

  if (val== 1) {
    return fake;
  }
  return ans;

  
')
dummy(FALSE)
dummy(TRUE)
```

Both of these function calls return `logical(0)`

Comment: Two thoughts - the vectors `fake` and `ans` probably need `PROTECT`ed even though I doubt garbage collection would be causing an issue. And while I am having trouble using `inline`, do you need to point to the value such as `int val = LOGICAL(x)[0]?0:1;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That doesn't sound right, but I also do not think your code goes about this in the right way.  In the still-small, still-fairly new package [tidyCpp](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/tidycpp) I am collecting a few convenience definitions.  One of its [examples](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/tidycpp/blob/master/inst/snippets/defineExamples.cpp)  is basically exactly your problem:

```
#include <tidyCpp>

// We use Rcpp here because it has cppFunction() and sourceCpp(). 
// We do not use any Rcpp headers.

// [[Rcpp::depends(tidyCpp)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
bool isItLogical(SEXP x) {
    return R::isLogical(x);
}

/*** R
isItLogical(TRUE)
isItLogical(FALSE)
isItLogical(42)
*/
```

When I `sourceCpp()` this (using `Rcpp` just for the convenience of building, no real `Rcpp` code here) I see

```
> Rcpp::sourceCpp("~/git/tidycpp/inst/snippets/defineExamples.cpp")

> 
isItLogical(TRUE)
[1] TRUE

> 
isItLogical(FALSE)
[1] TRUE

> 
isItLogical(42)
[1] FALSE
>
```

If we change it from `isLogical` (answering: is the incoming variable a boolean or not) to `asLogical` to return the boolean value instead it becomes

```
> Rcpp::sourceCpp("~/git/stackoverflow/66575428/answer.cpp")

> 
asLogical(TRUE)
[1] TRUE

> 
asLogical(FALSE)
[1] FALSE

> 
asLogical(42) # not zero so ...
[1] TRUE
>
```

New function below.

```
#include <tidyCpp>

// We use Rcpp here because it has cppFunction() and sourceCpp().
// We do not use any Rcpp headers.

// [[Rcpp::depends(tidyCpp)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
bool asLogical(SEXP x) {
    return R::asLogical(x);
}

/*** R
asLogical(TRUE)
asLogical(FALSE)
asLogical(42) # not zero so ...
*/
```

Obviously, you do not have to use `tidyCpp` and can just look at [its sources](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/tidycpp) to pick the respective C functions of the R API, but I find the naming conventions there a little inconsistent hence this small packages as a little shim around it...

Answer (score 1):

Use `asLogical` to convert function arguments (which are type `SEXP`, never `bool`) to bool:

```c
SEXP dummy(SEXP x) {
  int val = asLogical(x);
  if (val) {
    return allocVector(LGLSXP, 5);
  }
  return ScalarLogical(0);
}
```

(though I tend to agree with Dirk that Rcpp is almost always the way to go, unless is a peculiar aversion to it, especially as a first step from R to using compiled code with R).